# Hashed Directory Structure: is it efficient? How many files & dirs will be there?

Tags: linux, directory, storage

Recently I recently started working on a project that will handle millions of files. To store them I needed a good directory structure.

So, at first, I tried to store them by their upload date like this `2016/06/24/file_name.ext`. But I soon realized that it's a pretty bad idea.

After searching Google & reading some articles we found out about the hashed directory structure.

To test this idea I took a file and created an MD5 hash of the file. Then added some random character/salt to avoid a future hash collision.

So now the directory structure looks something like this:
`a/94a/8fe/a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3.ext`

Now, my questions are:

1. Is this method good/efficient? (OS: Linux)
2. Is 2 step depth is enough?
3. Maximum how many files each/last directory will contain?

I know that my root directory will have max `16` directory and every one of them will contain `16^3 = 4096`. Same will go for that `4096` directories. But I am unable to calculate how many files will `a/94a/8fe/` directory contain? is it `16^7`?

**Edits:**
File size can vary from 10MB to 15GB. And these files are stored in a server which works as a sorage server for the main site.

Suggest me different structure if you think this method is no good.

Advance thanks to you guys. English is not my first language so sorry for any grammatical error.

Please remove this question if it's a duplicate or somewhere it has been already discussed.

Comment: You've got a total of 16*4096*4096 directories, that is 268435456 directories, so most of them will be empty, unless you have hunderds of millions of files.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware But the last directory will always contain file(s). And I wanted to know maximum how many files will that directory have?

Comment: If you can put some restrictions on file size, using a proper database might be way faster. Milions of rows for a database is everyday bread.

Comment: Why don't use sql for tons of small data?

Comment: @IporSircer I am currently using DB to store the hash.

Comment: @KamilCuk what do you mean? Do you mean limiting the file size & storing them in DB?

Comment: Yes. Just think about limiting the file name size and for example for mysql the maximum TEXT type is LONGTEXT, which is up to 4GB. We don't know how big the files are. The best would be to use columns like 'bigint id, char(50?) name, timestamp creationdate, (SMALL/MEDIUM/LONG)TEXT or char(<big number>) content'. That way you are storing only the data you need (do you care about the inode numbers and permission to assigned to each(!) file?). The database will create hashes and speed up searches for you, you would need however to provide some abstraction to your applications.

Comment: @KamilCuk Sorry for not providing all the information. I have updated the question. File size can vary from 10MB to 15GB. I don't think using database is possible.

Comment: If you use a database table to find the files you could approach this differently: Simply number the directories and files. You can then fix the maximum number of files per directory. Say you put files `file0001.ext` to `file9999.ext` in each directory and you have `dir0001` to `dir9999` then you can store 100,000,000 files and you know exactly the maximum number of files per directory. You only need to store the directory and file number in the database. Need 10 billion files? Easy, just make the numbers bigger.

Comment: I would still vote to store that 15GB in multiple 4GB chunks in db. If you don't care about inode number and permissions to each file you will just lose space. May I ask, _why_ do you need a directory structure? What information will you need to provide to users? If users are interested in finding files created between one date and another, it's easier to just store all the files in one directory (ext4 has theoretically 4 bilion files per dir) and store file names and creation dates in db for fast searches.